How to modify how Pytorch ImageFolder assigns labels
I have a dataset that is stored in a directory as such:

I want all the images that belong to the same feature directory within the same image directory to get the same label. Essential the label assigned to an image should be based on the combination of "image#" and "feature_#" directories. I don't want the images that are in different image directories to be assigned the same label if they just share the same feature directory name. Is there a simple way to modify how ImageFolder assigns labels?
